# How to use mingw on linux to compile a fltk project to a windows executable?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mingw, codeblocks

I compiled a fltk application on linux with Code::blocks (file: test.cpp) without problems and was able to run the test.cpp file from within Code::blocks and from the linux command line.

Now I want to compile the test.cpp file or the whole project (prj.cbp) to a Windows 64 bit executable.

I installed mingw and it works fine because I can convert normal (NOT fltk) .cpp files to .exe files and run them on Windows.

But when I try to compile the test.cpp file with the mingw command (x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --static test.cpp -o app.exe) I get this error:

```
main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: FL/Fl.H: No such file or directory   
#include <FL/Fl.H>
         ^~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How can I fix this and how can I compile .cbp projects to get Windows binaries?  Is it possible to do this from in Code::blocks and how do I set the mingw compiler to find the FLTK libraries?

If I try to compile from Code::blocks with the mingw compiler under linux for Windows I get this build log:

`-------------- Build: Debug in newFLTKproject (compiler: MingW64 compiler)---------------

x86_64-linux-gnu-c++ -std=c++14 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_forms -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_gl -lGL -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_images -lpng -lz -lfltk_jpeg -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_images -lpng -lz -lfltk_jpeg -lfltk_gl -lGL -lfltk_forms -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -DWINVER=0x0400 -D__WIN95__ -D__GNUWIN32__ -DSTRICT -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -D__WINDOWS__ -std=c++14 -g -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_forms -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_gl -lGL -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_images -lpng -lz -lfltk_jpeg -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_images -lpng -lz -lfltk_jpeg -lfltk_gl -lGL -lfltk_forms -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -DWINVER=0x0400 -D__WIN95__ -D__GNUWIN32__ -DSTRICT -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -D__WINDOWS__ -std=c++14 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/FL/images -I/usr/include/uuid -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_forms -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_gl -lGL -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_images -lpng -lz -lfltk_jpeg -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -L/usr/local/lib -lfltk_images -lpng -lz -lfltk_jpeg -lfltk_gl -lGL -lfltk_forms -lfltk -lXrender -lXcursor -lXfixes -lXext -lXft -lfontconfig -lXinerama -lpthread -ldl -lm -lX11 -DWINVER=0x0400 -D__WIN95__ -D__GNUWIN32__ -DSTRICT -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -D__WINDOWS__ -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -I/usr/local/include/FL -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -I/usr/local/include/FL -I/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include -I/usr/local/include/FL -I/usr/local/include -c /home/melt/Documents/C++/FLTK_C++2020/newFLTKproject/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o bin/Debug/newFLTKproject obj/Debug/main.o  -lstdc++ -lgcc -lodbc32 -lwsock32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -ladvapi32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lXext -lX11 -lm -lfltkgl -lfltkforms -lfltkimages --use-forms --ldflags --use-gl --ldflags --use-images --ldflags --use-forms --use-gl --use-images --ldflags -lstdc++ -lgcc -lodbc32 -lwsock32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -ladvapi32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lXext -lX11 -lm -lfltkgl -lfltkforms -lfltkimages --use-forms --ldflags --use-gl --ldflags --use-images --ldflags --use-forms --use-gl --use-images --ldflags -lstdc++ -lgcc -lodbc32 -lwsock32 -lwinspool -lwinmm -lshell32 -lcomctl32 -lodbc32 -ladvapi32 -lodbc32 -lwsock32 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lXext -lX11 -lm -lfltkgl -lfltkforms -lfltkimages  /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib
/bin/sh: 1: x86_64-linux-gnu-c++: not found
Process terminated with status 127 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))`

Comment: Easiest solution; spin up a Windows VM and build your code natively on Windows. Cross compiling is a royal pain (IMHO).

Comment: @JesperJuhl some project use it successfully (e.g. Stockfish, the world's strongest chess engine, publishes its Windows binaries via mingw-w64 cross builds). Sticking to Standard C++ is a great help here of course

Comment: OP, it goes without saying you'd have to install Windows binaries for any library that your code is going to link against  (or build that library from source using the cross-compiler), have you done that?

Comment: @ Jesper Juhl I don't like using Windows and want to use only open source tools.  Further I'm used to compile my apps with Code::blocks so it would be nice if I also could compile graphic programs for Windows with the use of FLTK and mingw.

Comment: @ M.M I have Code::blocks, FLTK, FLUID and mingw installed and can compile from source to linux executables.  Now I want to use the source file, e.g. test.cpp that I used to compile to a linux executable, to compile to a windows executable with mingw.  An other option would be using Code::blocks to compile instantly to a windows executable, only I don't know how.  I've tried [this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Code::Blocks_and_Cross_Compilers) but after compiling without errors there's no executable file that was made by the compiler.